# Ajax Onchange Inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have ajax function

```
function price(id,prid,divid,key,name)
{  
        //alert(id); alert(prid); alert(name);
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "aid="+id+"&prid="+prid,
        url: '<?php echo base_url('grocery/onchange')?>',
        success: function(html){
        $('#'+divid).html(html);

        }
    });
}
```

i wrote this function for a select box Onchange.

```
    foreach($some as $name) {
        <select class="form-control"  onchange="price(this.value,'<?php echo $prd->pr_id;?>','ajax<?php echo $key?>','<?php echo $key?>','<?php echo $prd->pr_name ?>')">
//options
</select>
    }
```

What My problem is i change a div content using this function.But Only The first value from the loop only changes. others didn't work? It's because the function is in foreach loop.How to solve this??

Comment: PLease provide the full select code, with the options, adn the div structure.

Comment: Where is `$('#'+divid).html(html);` in your HTML? Please provide complete code.

Comment: If your making ajax request's in a loop like that(generally bad idea) you will need to make them `synchronous` by default they are `asynchronous`. However setting `async=>false` is a bad move!! You will need to look into `Deferred` methods as calling them all synchronously might lock up the thread.

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach loop you are not using dynamic parameters for every select, try to view source your code and find out that each selection have same parameters try to passout dynamic parameter for each select.

Comment: That's why i am passing 5 different parameters.but same problem?

Comment: Your should consider posting your complete code. Where is `$('#'+divid).html(html);` in HTML or code?

Comment: So please post the div HTML too. :) I have written something but its incomplete without it.

Comment: Share your complete code then I will let you know about what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it in different way as you have used earlier. Create all select boxes as follow:

```
foreach($some as $name) {
            <select class="form-control some_unique_class_name_that_not_used_in_css" data-prid ='<?php echo $prd->pr_id;?>' data-ajax ='ajax<?php echo $key?>' data-key = '<?php echo $key?>' data-name = '<?php echo $prd->pr_name ?>'
            >
             <option value="Some_Value0">Some_OPTION_name_0</option>
             <option value="Some_Value1">Some_OPTION_name_1</option>
             <option value="Some_Value2">Some_OPTION_name_2</option>
    </select>
    }
```

Set necessary parameters in "data-any_param_name_to_use" attributes so that you can access it in function.
  Now call jqueries change function for respective select boxes with class name as below:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '.some_unique_class_name_that_not_used_in_css', function() {
       var divid = $(this).attr('data-ajax');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "aid="+$(this).val()+"&prid="+$(this).attr('data-prid'),
            url: '<?php echo base_url('grocery/onchange')?>',
            success: function(html){
                $('#'+divid).html(html);
            }
        });
    });
  });

  // $(this).val() => selected value from the select box 
 // $(this).attr('data-prid') => whatever prid you have saved for the respective select box
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Where you are going to assign `$('#'+divid).html(html);` in HTML code?

Comment: Thanks For Your Response. I replace by your code. but it works in the same way :(